# Rocket chip simulation shows unexpected instruction count

Tags: riscv, chisel, verilator, rocket-chip

The following two code snippets differ only the value loaded into the x23
register, but the `minstret` instruction counts (reported by a Verilator
simulation of the Rocket chip) differ substantially.  Is this a bug, or am I
doing something wrong?

The `read_csr()` function is from the RISC-V Frontend Server Library (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-fesvr/blob/master/fesvr/encoding.h), and the rest of the code [syscalls.c, crt.S, test.ld] is similar to the RISC-V benchmarks
(https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tests/tree/master/benchmarks/common).

I have checked that the compiled binaries contain the exact same instructions, except for the difference in the operands.

Dividing 0x0fffffff by 0xff, repeating 1024 times: **3260 instructions**.

```
size_t instrs = 0 - read_csr(minstret);

asm volatile (
        "mv             x20,    zero;"
        "li             x21,    1024;"
        "li             x22,    0xfffffff;"
        "li             x23,    0xff;"

    "loop:"
        "div            x24,  x22,  x23;"
        "addi           x20,  x20,  1;"
        "bleu           x20,  x21,  loop;"

    ::: "x20", "x21", "x22", "x23", "x24", "cc"
);

instrs += read_csr(minstret);
```

Dividing 0x0fffffff by 0xffff, repeating 1024 times: **3083 instructions**.

```
size_t instrs = 0 - read_csr(minstret);

asm volatile (
        "mv             x20,    zero;"
        "li             x21,    1024;"
        "li             x22,    0xfffffff;"
        "li             x23,    0xffff;"

    "loop:"
        "div            x24,  x22,  x23;"
        "addi           x20,  x20,  1;"
        "bleu           x20,  x21,  loop;"

    ::: "x20", "x21", "x22", "x23", "x24", "cc"
);

instrs += read_csr(minstret);
```

Here, 3083 instructions seems correct (1024 * 3 = 3072).  Since `minstret` counts retired instructions, it seems strange that first example executed ~200 more instructions.  These results are always the same no matter how many times I run these two programs.

Comment: what does the full dissassembly look like including the code that reads the instruction counter?

Comment: Disassembly for the 0xff case: http://termbin.com/p713 and for the 0xffff case: http://termbin.com/mrj9. The function addresses differ, so vimdiff isn't very helpful, but if you look for the `loop` symbol, you'll be able to locate the above snippets.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the code that reads the instruction counter is just `csrr a5,minstret`.

Comment: hmmm, I see what you are saying.  I dont remember if they open sourced their logic, perhaps there is a shortcut in the divide based on values, but that wouldnt make sense either.  Was hoping it was something simple like alignment or a slight build difference.  But that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: Have you approached them on this?

Comment: Thanks! I haven't approached them about this yet, but I will create a new issue on the repository, and report back what I find there.

Comment: What two platforms are you comparing against?  RocketChip simulated using Verilator vs. ???

Comment: How is the li pseudo instruction implemented on your two platforms?

Comment: @edc I am comparing two binaries (that differ in the operand value) on the same platform (Rocket chip simulated using Verilator). The `li` pseudo instruction is outside the loop, so as I understand, it shouldn't be the culprit behind the 200 extra instructions. The assembly code produced by objdump [termbin.com/p713, termbin.com/mrj9] unfortunately doesn't expand the `li` pseudo instruction.

Comment: ooh,, I didnt see that last night these are not the same binary with just the constants changed, there are a lot of differences.   and for the test loop the alignment is different.   try the test again with the alignment of the loop matching for both and see what you see...that by itself could explain what you are seeing.  (I demonstrate such things all the time, same machine code taking a different amount of time simply due to alignment)...

Comment: Resolved it over on the issue list of the repository [https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/issues/1495]. I will post the "answer" below, if it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved at https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/issues/1495.

Servicing the debug interrupt, which is apparently used by the simulation to know whether the benchmark has finished executing, caused the differences in the instruction count.  The verbose log produced by Verilator shows the debug address range (0x800 onwards) being injected at different points during the execution.